# laravel5.1 check size of upload (validator fails on validate size)

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to check the size of a file uploaded to the server?
I tried to use this code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'departments' => 'exists:departments,id',
    'attachment' =>'min:1|max:1500|mimes:txt,text,log,jpeg,bmp,png',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) 
       return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

When I try to upload for example the GIT setup (around 29MB), the upload works and I get a warning message from PHP. I've set maximum upload size of file to 8MB in php.ini. I want to show the user a message saying file is too big. The Problem I noticed is the large file isn't registered by the validator? Any idea how I can validate this?

Comment: If a file is bigger than the maximum upload size in the php.ini, then the upload will fail and the element error of the upload field in `$_FILES` will be set to 1. I'm not sure how Laravel handles that (I don't use Laravel), but here is the documentation about PHP Fileuploads http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. Check the Laravel docs for more information about how Laravel handles such errors.